# SOAP request in iOS

Tags: ios, soap

I have this SOAP request that I use in php to get some information, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Xcode, hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction

```
<?php
$wsdl_url = "https://www.service.com/mySoapService.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

try {
    $userName = 'myUsername';
    $password = 'myPassword';
    $result = $client->retrieveUsage(new SoapParam(array("UserId" => $userName, "Password" => $password), "RetrieveUsageRequestType"));

    print '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
    print '</pre>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is XML-RPC an option? There are a few XML-RPC options available out there for iOS, maybe one would work better than SOAP?

Comment: This is PHP code, not Objective-C. Do you expect us to port the code for you, or have you actually tried writing some Objective-C yourself? If the latter, please post what you've tried.

Comment: I've added the PHP code as an example, so it's more clear what I want, I don't need the ported code, just a push in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your WSDL, create stubs and off you go, start using your web-service from iOS apps.

http://sudzc.com/

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Enjoy!